# The user profile link in chat is to StackOverflow, not Mathematica.se

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When clicking on a user in chat, there are two "user profile" links provided. The first links to the chatroom user profile, but the second is supposed to link to the user on the associated site. But, in this case, it points to StackOverflow, not Mathematica.se.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design.

The second link leads to the user's profile on the site they set as their parent site. For example, mine is [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), so the second chat profile link will take you to my profile there.

Users who first join chat from Mathematica will have it set as their parent site by default.

To change your parent site:

- Go to your chat user profile by clicking on your avatar in a chat room and using the first "user profile" link
- click [change] beside the Parent User field.

Comment: My profile on chat profile on [math.se] shows up with a link back to my profile on [math.se] not SO. So, does your own icon link back to the profile on the current site you're on?

Comment: @rcollyer Your chat user's parent site is set to Mathematics so you will see a link to your Math.SE profile regardless of which SE chat room you're in.

Comment: odd, didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: @AnnaLear - how does one change one's "parent user"?

Comment: @Verbeia Go to your chat user profile (you can get there by clicking on your avatar in a chat room and using the first "user profile" link), and then click `[change]` beside the Parent User field.

Comment: @AnnaLear (I later found the instructions in the chat room) - could you please add this to your answer? I think others would find this helpful.